# Django FormWizard NamedUrl problems

Tags: python, django, django-formwizard

I'm trying to use NamedUrlSessionWizardView with my form wizard in order to have each step of the form have it's own separate url. However there seems to be minimal documentation so I am having a hard time getting it to work properly.

Right now I am able to enter the url (example.com/form/1) and get each step to display. However for some reason the templates are not displaying the fields for each step, so I can't enter any information. I checked the django debug toolbar and it says that the form is not valid:

```
'wizard': {'form': <CompanyDetailsForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(name;state;city;funding_level;products_offered)>
```

Urls.py:

```
from .views import DataRequestWizardView, step_3_condition, step_4_condition, data_request_forms
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="landing.html")),
    url(r'^start/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="start.html"), name='start'),
    url(r'^form/(?P<step>.+)/$', DataRequestWizardView.as_view(data_request_forms, url_name="product_wizard_step"), name='product_wizard_step'),
    url(r'^form/$', DataRequestWizardView.as_view(data_request_forms, url_name="product_wizard_step"), name='product_wizard'),
]
```

Views:

```
    data_request_forms = (
        ("1", forms.CompanyDetailsForm),
        ("2", forms.DataRequestForm1),
        ("3", forms.DataRequestForm2),
        ("4", forms.DataRequestForm3),
        ("5", forms.DataRequestForm4),
        ("6", forms.DataRequestForm5)
    )

class DataRequestWizardView(NamedUrlSessionWizardView):    
    instance = None
    def get_template_names(self):
        return ['step_{0}_template.html'.format(self.steps.current)]

    def get_step_url(self, step):
        return reverse('canareeform:product_wizard_step', kwargs={'step':step})

    def get_form_instance( self, step ):
        if self.instance is None:
            self.instance = DataRequest()
        return self.instance

    def done( self, form_list, form_dict, **kwargs ):
        form_dict={}
        for x in form_list:
            form_dict=dict(form_dict.items()+x.cleaned_data.items())
        company = CompanyDetail(name=form_dict['name'], state=form_dict['state'], city=form_dict['city'], funding_level=form_dict['funding_level'], products_offered=form_dict['products_offered'])
        company.save()
        request = self.instance
        request.company = company
        request.save()
        return render_to_response('done.html', {'form_data' : form_data})
```

It was working before I changed to NamedUrl and then with only a few edits, the fields are not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. My template files are named: step_0_template.html, step_1_template, etc. The correct template is served up by this function:

```
 def get_template_names(self):
    return ['step_{0}_template.html'.format(self.steps.current)]
```

However when I changed to NamedUrl it started indexing the templates starting at 1 rather than 0. So I just added 1 to all the template names.